# Auto renewed SSL certificates for many servers

Tags: http, https, lets-encrypt

We have a large distributed network of Asterisk systems that are now required to talk to a provisioning server via HTTPS. Currently, we are using a wildcard certificate which has been added to both the provisioning server and the Asterisk systems using out subdomain. However, according to [this](https://www.venafi.com/blog/wildcard-certificates-make-encryption-easier-but-less-secure), using a wildcard certificate, especially with a large amount of systems, is less secure.

A solution we have come up with has been to make use of Let's Encrypt which will enable us to have a unique SSL certificate for each system. According to [this](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/), we will have to do one of the following:

1. Use the HTTP-01 challenge method and open up port 80 to the world (not possible most of our servers since port 80 and 443 are only open certain IPs if at all - also rules out TLS challenges)
2. Use the DNS-01 challenge method and have the potential of even higher risk since each system will require our DNS API credentials (ultimately an attacker could cause chaos if they compromised any system that has our DNS API credentials)

So my questions are as follows:

1. Are there any other options? We are happy to pay for certificates if that is what is required.
2. If we have to use the DNS-01 challenge, is there a way we can reduce our attack surface (i.e. API access to only certain DNS records)?

Comment: Perhaps use a reverse proxy which does the SSL offload?

Comment: We have been thinking that something like [this](https://github.com/joohoi/acme-dns) might work for us.